# Typescript generic constraint that uses inferred method return type

Tags: typescript

i have this scenario:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
  abstract getData(): T;
  getBase(): Partial<T> {
    return {};
  }
}

interface Contract {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}

class Impl extends AbstractClass<Contract> {
  get prop1() {
    // some complex logic here
    return '';
  }

  getBase() {
    return {
      prop2: 'foo'
    }
  }
}
```

how do i express the constraint **correct implementation of `AbstractClass` has to cover all properties from `Contract` interface**? simple solution is `Impl implements Contract`, but then i will have to duplicate declarations for all properties that do not have a complex logic getter. so it would be nice to be able to also use inferred type of `getBase()` implementation.
the goal is to have a compile-time error if there is no value provided either on `Impl` itself or as property of inferred return type of `getBase()`.
is it possible in principle using Typescript?

Comment: So in your example, `Impl` is implemented correctly.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, it is. it's just i want `tsc` to complain if it isn't.

Comment: So, if I undestand curectly `ReturnType<getBase> & Fields<Impl>` has to have all properties of `Contract` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, that's true. is it possible to express this constraint on `Impl` or `AbstractClass` in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `getBase` abstract and specify that the return must be the difference of the properties of the current class and the interface, you will get a compile time error if the property is not in either the result of `getBase` or the class:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T, TThis> {
    abstract getBase(): { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof TThis>]: T[P] };
}
interface Contract {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}

class Impl extends AbstractClass<Contract, Impl> {
    get prop1() {
        // some complex logic here
        return '';
    }

    getBase() {
        return {
            prop2: ""
        }
    }
}

class ImplWrong  extends AbstractClass<Contract, ImplWrong> {
    get prop1() {
        // some complex logic here
        return '';
    }

    getBase() { // error Property 'getBase' in type 'ImplWrong' is not assignable to the same property in base type
        return {
            prop3: "" 
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that I had to pass the class itself as a type argumentto the base class, using the `this` type is not a solution as the keys of `this` are never fully known.

Also `getBase` must return at the very least the difference between `Impl` and `Contract` but it could return more properties (typescript allows implementations to return a super type of the implementation method). So if you have `prop1` in both the class and the return of `getBase` it will not be an error.

Comment: @ilj sure, give it a try, I'm still thinking about it myself, I am not 100% pleased as you might be able to specify the property in both the return type and the Impl class which might lead to errors

Comment: @ilj There was a small error in the in the properties for return type of `getBase` it should be `{ [P in ..]: T[P] }` not `{ [P in ...]: string }` as it originally was

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to add constraint for `Impl` class, and leave `getBase` return type inferred:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
  abstract getData(): T;
  getBase(): Partial<T> {
    return {};
  }
}

interface Contract {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}


type ImplConstraint<T, I extends AbstractClass<T>> = 
  { [n in Exclude<keyof T, keyof ReturnType<I['getBase']>>]: T[n] };

class Impl extends AbstractClass<Contract> implements ImplConstraint<Contract, Impl>  {
  get prop1() {
    // some complex logic here
    return '';
  }

  getBase() {
    return {
      prop2: 'foo'
    }
  }

  getData(): Contract {
       return {} as Contract;    
  }  

}

class ImplWrong extends AbstractClass<Contract> implements ImplConstraint<Contract, ImplWrong>  {

// Class 'ImplWrong' incorrectly implements interface 
//  'ImplConstraint<Contract, Impl>'
//       Property 'prop1' is missing in type 'ImplWrong'.

  get prop11() {
    // some complex logic here
    return '';
  }

  getBase() {
    return {
      prop2: 'foo'
    }
  }

  getData(): Contract {
       return {} as Contract;    
  }  

}
```

Comment: Also a very good solution, I was just exploring it, the drawback is the implementer has to know they have to implement the interface

Comment: @artem, this is a little more complex than what @titian suggested. might work better for even more complex scenario though, where you have multiple different `ImplConstraint` types that need to be implemented.

Comment: Yes, and you also have to remember to pass correct `Impl`  class for `ImplConstraint`, it's easy to mix up and I don't know of a good way to refer to "this" class when you add class constraint like this.